# angular ui.router tilt transition between two states

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to wrap my head around the how I would go to implement a tilt transition between the two views below.  Currently it just replaces the ui-view in the root, and the map is not longer there.

if my config is:

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"])
.config([
   "$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider",
   function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
      $stateProvider
         .state("app", {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div ui-view="header"></div><div>Content</div>'
         })
         .state("app.map", {
             url: '/',
             views: {
                "header": {
                   template: '<button ng-click="menu()">Menu</button>',
                   controller: function($scope, $state) {
                      $scope.menu = function(){
                          $state.transitionTo("app.login");
                      };
                   }
                }
             }
         })
         .state("app.login", {
            url: '/login',
            views: {
                "@": {
                   template: '<div>Login<button ng-click="close()">Close</button></div>',
                   controller: function($scope, $state){
                      $scope.close = function(){
                         $state.transitionTo("app.map");
                      };
                   }
                }
            }
         });
   }
])
```

/index.html ( has all necessary scripts and css )

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
   <body>
      <div id="page">
         <div ui-view></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how I would go about this?  I'm lost

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're doing absolute targeting of views, you need to use the `view@state` syntax (looks like you're not doing that for `header`).

For your login state, I'm guessing you want to do `"header@app"` instead of `"@"` (I know, it's confusing, I'm trying to fix it).

Finally, if you're trying to animate the contents of your `header` view, you just need to an an `ng-animate` directive to the element.

Hope that helps.